# Basic Erlang module troubles

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

So I straight up copy and pasted the code from the Erlang docs: https://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/modules.html#module-syntax

[image: This should explain everything]

Please help!

Comment: Did you compile the module? Try `c(m).` and then `m:fact(1).`

Comment: Yep, I forgot the `m:` before `fact(1).` such a silly mistake. Everything works now!

Answer (score 4):

The module didn't compiled. To fix it try this in the Erlang shell (eshell):

```erlang
1> c(m).
ok
2> m:fact(1).
1
```

See documentation on how [code loading](https://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/code_loading.html) works.

Comment: After compiling the module m and trying to run `fact(1).` I get the following error: `** exception error: undefined shell command fact/1`

Answer (score 0):

`exception error: undefined shell command`
almost always means that the shell environment does not have the intended function, which can also mean that the module which contains its definition has not been loaded for all the code that we write by our hand and execute. You can deliberately try to misspell some auto loaded BIF(s) for example "length1" and you will still see same message showing up.